# PHP Session working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php

Thanks to be into this matter, I am having trouble to login in with session variable on server, while it's working perfect on localhost. Here is my code.

My landing page

```
<?php
require_once 'lock.php';
?>
My HTML code will be here....
```

**lock.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'includes/connect.php';
if(empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location: login.php?action=not_yet_logged_in');
}
$action = $_GET['action'];
if($action=='logout'){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: login.php?action=logout');
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'includes/connect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])==true){
    header('Location: index.php?action=already_logged_in');
}
?>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
if($_GET['action']=='not_yet_logged_in'){
    echo "<div class='infoMesssage'>You cannot go to the index page because you are not yet logged in.</div>";
    }else if($_GET['action']=='logout'){
        echo "<div class='infoMesssage'>You have scuccessfully logout.</div>";
    }
}                   

 if($_POST){
    $enUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $enPassword = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username = 'mockadmin';
        $password = 'mockadmin';
    }else {
        $chLogin = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from admin where user_name="'.$enUsername.'" AND password="'.$enPassword.'"');
        $chUser = mysqli_fetch_object($chLogin);

        $userId = $chUser->id;
        $username = $chUser->user_name;
        $password = $chUser->password;
    }

    if($_POST['username']==$username && $_POST['password']==$password){
      $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
      header('Location: index.php');                
   } else{
      echo "<div class='failedMessage'>Access denied. :(</div>";
   }
}
?>
<form class="m-t" method="post" role="form" action="login.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="btnlogin" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
</form>
```

My database **connect.php**

```
<?php  
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'liveuser', 'livepass', 'mocktest');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

I will appreciate your help. Thanks Again.

Comment: I would first try doing `print_r($_SESSION)` on your pages just to see how it is set and with what values.  Also, `empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])` is not going to work as you might expect as in other files, this is a boolean value (true/false).  empty conditional is meant to check for empty string var contents.

Comment: Please elaborate further on which parts are working and which are not working on the non-localhost server.

Comment: not an answer, but you are wide open to sql injection, and it is not a good idea to store passwords as plain text. [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Try starting session in your DB connection file and landing page as well.

Comment: Sorry to reply late, but I was not here. Thanks for the quicker reply. First of All I need to confirm that code is working perfect in my locahost. But in server, login page is returning with Access denied error.

Comment: Is it access denied in an apache way?  Can you put a screenshot?  If it is access denied via apache you may want to check the unix file permissions.  Depending on the server, the 'owner' of the files should be set to either apache or www-data.  Also you don't ever want to set any file at permission 777.  Check your files as they are on the server and google for the best settings numbers for permissions.

Comment: Here is the screen shot, It's working in local but when I tried same thing in live server this is happening.
[link](http://pingashcms.com/images/login-access-denied.jpg)